# Get color from category in Plotly Coordinates Plot

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

I want to crate a Coordinates Plot:

```
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(newdf, 
                          color="Type_enc", 
                          dimensions=["Attack","Defense","HP","Sp.Attack","Sp.Defense","Speed"],
                         color_continuous_scale=[[0, 'green'], [1, 'red']],
                         color_continuous_midpoint=0.5,
                         title ="Pokemon Stats by Type")
fig.show()
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

How do I change to legend to a discrete scale? So that instead of the encoded number, I just get "Fire" and "Water"? I tried changing

```
color="Type"
```

but this results in an error

```
Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of parcoords.line
    Invalid elements include: ['FIRE', 'FIRE', 'FIRE', 'FIRE', 'FIRE', 'WATER', 'WATER', 'WATER', 'WATER', 'FIRE']
```

Thank you!

Comment: You were not too far, there is a working example [here](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale) ! I believe it's precisely what you want.

Comment: At least for the colorscale. I'm not sure about the colorscale entries...

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Yes, my main problems is with the entries... I want the labels to be "FIRE" and "WATER", not the encoded value.

Comment: I didn't see it at first, on the same page as the [previous example](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/), look for "Customizing Tick Text on Discrete Color Bars", you'll find an example of `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(...)`, with discrete entries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, that should do the trick:

```py
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(newdf, 
                          color="Type_enc", 
                          dimensions=["Attack","Defense","HP","Sp.Attack","Sp.Defense","Speed"],
                          color_continuous_scale=[(0.0, "green"), (0.5, "green"), 
                                                 (0.5, "red"), (1.0, "red")],
                          title ="Pokemon Stats by Type")

fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
    title="Type",
    tickvals=[0,1],
    ticktext=["Water","Fire"], # You might want to change the order here!
    ))

fig.show()
```